# Declaring multiple State variables inline SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, variables, swiftui, swift5

SwiftUI's noob here trying to make

```
 @State var One, Two : Int = 0
```

INSTEAD

```
 @State var One : Int = 0
 @State Two : Int = 0
```

is possible to make that?

(This is easy but I need to use an entire model)

I don't know if init() should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SwiftUI manages the storage of any property you declare as a state. When the state value changes, the view invalidates its appearance and recomputes the body. Use the state as the single source of truth for a given view.

Unfortunately what you are asking is impossible, when you try to declare more than one variable on a single line, you will get this error from xcode:

```
property wrapper can only be applied to a single variable
```

Another way to do it, if you want to declare more than one variable on a single line it would be done like this:

```
@State var first = false; @State var second = false
```

You need to use `;` to separate the variables from each other.

Comment: Thank you so much it's clear that Swift UI is pretty different and they have rules haha lol

Comment: @AntonioLabra For now yes lol, you don't know, maybe in few months or a year apple will make an update that will allow us to do this.